# Install SCOM ( System Center Operation Manager ) on Azure VM with ARM Template

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, scom

Does anyone have a sample **ARM Template** to install **SCOM** agent on an Azure VM ?

I searched through Microsoft docs but couldn't find an example.

Also, What are the other critic points during operating this task?
Could you go through the steps?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   You can surely install SCOM agent through custom script extension in an ARM template as below. Use a SAS token to download the SCOM agent installation package, viz., MOMAgent.msi in the Azure VM during deployment itself and then use a powershell script to invoke the silent install of SCOM agent.

ARM Template: -

Using the default quickstart template for deploying an Azure VM through ARM template as given in this link : -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-template?toc=/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/toc.json

In this template, you must add the below custom script extension installation content in ‘resources’ section in the above ARM template. Please check the formatting of the ARM template code correctly, i.e., commas, curly brackets, square brackets, etc. Also, ensure to open HTTPS port 443 inbound also as below. Please ensure that the required ports for successful communication between SCOM Management Server and the SCOM agent installed on the Azure VM are opened as below through the addition of various security rules: -

```
"securityRules": [
      {
        "name": "default-allow-3389",
        "properties": {
          "priority": 1000,
          "access": "Allow",
          "direction": "Inbound",
          "destinationPortRange": "3389",
          "protocol": "Tcp",
          "sourcePortRange": "*",
          "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
          "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "AllowHTTPSInBound",
        "properties": {
          "priority": 1010,
          "access": "Allow",
          "direction": "Inbound",
          "destinationPortRange": "443",
          "protocol": "Tcp",
          "sourcePortRange": "*",
          "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
          "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
        }
      }
]
```

For including the custom script extension in your Azure VM deployment, kindly add the below ARM template commands as stated above.

```
   {
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/', 'InstallWebServer')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',parameters('vmName'))]"
          ],
        "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "protectedSettings": {
          "storageAccountName": "SCOM",
          "storageAccountKey": "EN6iUzOfVe8Ht0xvyxnqK/iXEGTEunznASsumuz0FR4SCvc2mFFHUJfbMy1/GSK7gXk0MB38MMo7+AStoKxC/w==",
          "fileUris": [
            "https://SCOM.blob.core.windows.net/SCOMAgent/Testdemo2.ps1"
          ],
          "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Testdemo2.ps1"
        }
      }
    }
```

Also, please note that you need to provision a storage account container already for storing the powershell script and the application package in it so that you can use that storage account’s key, its name and the powershell script’s blob URI in place of the same as requested above. Also, please change the name of the powershell script to be executed through the extension in ‘commandToExecute’ section. I have used the name of the script as ‘Testdemo2.ps1’ so have entered the blob URI of that script and its name accordingly in the ARM template above.

Once the above has been done, please ensure the successful execution of silent installation commands for the SCOM agent to be installed locally so that they can be accordingly modified in the powershell script. Please find my powershell script as below. Ensure that this script and the MOMAgent.msi is uploaded beforehand, and the access level of the container is set to ‘Anonymous and public access’: -

```
 Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
 Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -AllowClobber -Force
 Import-Module -Name Az.Storage -Force
 $StorageAccountName = "SCOM"
 $ContainerName = "SCOMAgent"
 $Blob1Name = "MOMAgent.msi"
 $TargetFolderPath = "C:\"
 $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -SASToken "sp=r&st=2022-02-10T08:40:34Z&se=2022-02-10T16:40:34Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=b&sig=DRDulljKTJiRbVPAXAJkTHi8QlnlbjPpVR3aueEf9xU%3D"
 Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $Blob1Name -Container $ContainerName -Context $context -Destination $TargetFolderPath
 $arg="/I C:\MOMAgent.msi /QN USE_SETTINGS_FROM_AD=1 MANAGEMENT_GROUP=MGname MANAGEMENT_SERVER_DNS=MSname SECURE_PORT=PortNumber ACTIONS_USE_COMPUTER_ACCOUNT=0 ACTIONSUSER=UserName ACTIONSDOMAIN=DomainName ACTIONSPASSWORD=Password INSTALLDIR=C:\ProgramFiles\ AcceptEndUserLicenseAgreement=1"
 Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList $arg ’
```

If you intend to modify the above arguments as stated by me for SCOM agent installation on the Azure VM, please refer to the documentation link below. It clearly explains the various command line arguments to be passed for SCOM agent installation. Please note that these arguments depend on your existing SCOM Server setup and configuration settings so accordingly ensure to open/modify the port settings accordingly for Azure VM as well as for other components in the SCOM setup.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/manage-deploy-windows-agent-manually?view=sc-om-2019#to-deploy-the-operations-manager-agent-from-the-command-line

Then edit the parameters file with the desired values in ‘adminUsername’, ‘adminPassword’ and ‘location’ and save it in the same location where template file is stored and execute the commands below from powershell console with elevated privileges locally, i.e., through the path where these ARM template files are stored by browsing to that path in powershell itself.

```
az login
az deployment group create -n <name of the deployment> -g <name of the resource group> --template-file "azuredeployVM.json" --parameters "azuredeployVM.parameters.json" ’
```

Thus, after successful deployment, you will be able to see the SCOM agent installed during the VM creation itself. In this way, you can install the SCOM agent in Azure VM through ARM template with storage account provisioning.